# AHBottomNavigation, how to create a sub fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using AHBottomNavigation. (https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation).
I have 3 Fragments for each bottomNavigation item. When I'm in the first fragment, (hosting a RecyclerView) I need to be able to launch a new (sub)screen and be able to go back to the recyclerView when backButton is pressed. I also need to stay in the AHBottomNavigation ViewPager...

Any idea about how to design/implement this behaviour?

Maybe it is very easy to do, but I can't figure it out...
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a non-swipeable view pager for the 3 fragments. Assign the view pager an id of something like @+id/container.

When you want to launch the subscreen, use a fragment transaction and replace @+id/container. Don't forget to also add the new fragment to the backstack.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.container, Subfragment.newInstance(),Subfragment.class.getName())
  .addToBackStack(Subfragment.class.getName())
  .commit();
```

The part that is a little unconventional would be having this subfragment, while still showing the bottom navigation. If you really want this functionality, I'm assuming that when you want to remove the subfragment when a different tab is clicked.

So in this case, when a tab is clicked, check and see if the subfragment exists, if it does, either popBackStack() or remove the subfragment, then switch to the desired fragment.

This is just one method. You could also write a PagerAdapter that replaces a fragment inside the viewpager.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll will look into it later :)